# Perform dot product on both sides of equation

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have an equation with two vectors:

$$\pmb{a} = 5\pmb{b}$$

Can we perform dot product on both sides with the same vector like this?

$$\pmb{a·c} = 5\pmb{b·c}$$

If so how could we prove that this a valid operation?

Comment: The vector function $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{c}$ is well-defined. But it is not bijective so note that we only have$$\mathbf{a}=5\mathbf{b}\implies \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c}=5\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can dot both sides with the same vector. If $\boldsymbol{a} = 5\boldsymbol{b}$, then by definition of equality, we have $\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{c} = \left(5\boldsymbol{b}\right) \cdot \boldsymbol{c}$. By the definition of the dot product, it is linear in both inputs (being an inner product on a vector space), so $\left(5\boldsymbol{b}\right) \cdot \boldsymbol{c} = 5\left(\boldsymbol{b} \cdot \boldsymbol{c}\right) = 5\boldsymbol{b} \cdot \boldsymbol{c}$. Thus $\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{c} = 5\boldsymbol{b} \cdot \boldsymbol{c}$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks! If we have an equation $\pmb{a} = m\pmb{b}$ would it therefore be correct to assume that by applying dot product on both sides we can calculate m like this $m = (\pmb{a} ⋅\pmb{b})/(\pmb{b} ⋅\pmb{b})$ or $m = (\pmb{a} ⋅\pmb{a})/(\pmb{b} ⋅\pmb{a})$

Comment: No, because $\boldsymbol{a}$ might not be a scalar multiple of $\boldsymbol{b}$. What you can say is that **if** the equation $\boldsymbol{a} = m\boldsymbol{b}$ has a solution, then that solution can be expressed as $m = \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b}/\boldsymbol{b} \cdot \boldsymbol{b}$ or $\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{a} / \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b}$.

Comment: And the equation can only have a solution when a is scalar multiple of b right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: @Prasiortle The equation _says_ that $\mathbf a$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf b$.